# oauth2 support for authlogic: the authlogic_oauth2 gem does not work / is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, authlogic, oauth-2.0

I am building an app that uses authlogic and requires authentication through Facebook through the Oauth2 framework. I thought this was going to be a piece of cake using the authlogic_oauth2 gem http://github.com/haraldmartin/authlogic_oauth2. However, after running bundle, my server nor any rails generators would work (as described here: [Server won't start on using authlogic-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486798/server-wont-start-on-using-authlogic-oauth2)).

I tried to run bundle install with the gem hosted by robdimarco like so:

```
gem 'authlogic_oauth2', :git => 'git:github.com/robdimarco/authlogic_oauth2.git'
```

But that threw up the error:

```
ssh: connect to host git port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there no more support for oauth2 in authlogic? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Ok. Simple solution by a bit more research:
This is the correct gem to go into your gemfile.
`gem "robdimarco_authlogic_oauth2", "~> 1.1.4"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:git => 'git://github.com/robdimarco/authlogic_oauth2.git'`, not `:git => 'git:github.com/robdimarco/authlogic_oauth2.git'`.

(Typo at the beginning of the URL.)